# How to make btn go to new page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, submit

How would I use the following button so when clicked it goes to new page?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
```

I need this button when clicked to go to a search.php

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite that, because you can do like this too,

```
<a href="newpage.html" class="btn btn-default">Search</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript 
`<button onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>` 
or you can use html and create a link and add css class btn btn-default like here
 `<a class="btn btn-default" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`